# Printing from same index

Tags: python, lambda

If I would like to create a list and print just the country names in the same index as the proper gdp values that have a gdp greater than 3000.
How should I go about doing that? Do I use zip?

```
country=[Australia, Japan, India, China]
gdp= [3000, 7000, 5000, 4200]

h=list(filter(lambda x: x > 3000,  gdp))
```

Comment: Yes, use zip. Was there a particular problem when you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` within a list-comprehension like this example:

```
country = ['Australia', 'Japan', 'India', 'China']
gdp = [3000, 7000, 5000, 4200]
out = [k for k, v in zip(country, gdp) if v > 3000]
print(out)
```

Output:

```
['Japan', 'India', 'China']
```